# Peek on QTextStream

Tags: qt, seek, peek, qtextstream

I would like to peek the next characters of a QTextStream reading a QFile, in order to create an efficient tokenizer.

However, I don't find any satisfying solution to do so.

```
QFile f("test.txt");
f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
f.write("Hello world\nHello universe\n");
f.close();

f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QTextStream s(&f);
int i = 0;
while (!s.atEnd()) {
  ++i;
  qDebug() << "Peek" << i << s.device()->peek(3);
  QString v;
  s >> v;
  qDebug() << "Word" << i << v;
}
```

Gives the following output:

```
Peek 1 "Hel" # it works only the first time
Word 1 "Hello" 
Peek 2 "" 
Word 2 "world" 
Peek 3 "" 
Word 3 "Hello" 
Peek 4 "" 
Word 4 "universe" 
Peek 5 "" 
Word 5 ""
```

I tried several implementations, also with QTextStream::pos() and QTextStream::seek(). It works better, but pos() is buggy (returns -1 when the file is too big).

Does anyone have a solution to this recurrent problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: add to the logs `s.device()->pos()` and `s.device()->bytesAvailable()` to check progress of device reading. This may help to locate the problem.

Comment: Before the first QTextStream::operator>>: (pos = 0, bytesAvailable = 27). Just after it and until the end: (pos = 27, bytesAvailable = 0). The buggy behavior of Qt seems indeed related

Comment: I've check [QTextStream code](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/ba8342071d05336c7b7f5ff8182a2ba9000c9b53:src/corelib/io/qtextstream.cpp). It looks like it always caches as much data as possible and there is no way to disable this behavior. I was expecting that it will use peek on device, but it only reads in greedy way. Bottom line is that you can't use `QTextStream` in this case.

Comment: Yes. I also tried to set the QTextStream and the QFile unbuffered (from the constructor), but it's doesn't help, too.

Comment: My opinion is that a function like QTextStream::peek(int size) is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You peek from `QIODevice`, but then you read from `QTextStream`, that's why peek works only once. Try this:

```
while (!s.atEnd()) {
      ++i;
      qDebug() << "Peek" << i << s.device()->peek(3);
      QByteArray v = s.device()->readLine ();
      qDebug() << "Word" << i << v;
}
```

Unfortunately, `QIODevice` does not support reading single words, so you would have to do it yourself with a combination of peak and read.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. The example I wrote is extremely simplified. In my concrete example, I am interesting in using intensively the QTextStream::operator>>.

Comment: The issue is indeed that QTextStream::device() is not synchronized with QTextStream. And that there is no peeking function on QTextStream directly.

Comment: That's true, but since there is no method for reading a word in QIODevice, and pos() is buggy, my advice would be to implement word-by-word reading for QIODevice yourself and use it instead of QTextStream::operator>>. Or is there a reason why it must be this operator?

Comment: Yes, you're completely right. In fact, during the discussion, I choose this solution and implemented it :-) Using QTextStream is very convenient to write a simple and good-looking code. It's a pity there is not a peek function in this class, destroying the possibility to write a real tokenizer using this class (where peek is required to parse an ambiguous language)

Comment: @FabienRohrer IIRC, QTextStream either succeeds at reading or leaves the input undisturbed. Thus it should be fine to attempt to, say, read a number, and if it fails, then you can read a word.

Answer (score 0):

Try [disable `QTextStream::autoDetectUnicode`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextstream.html#autoDetectUnicode). This may read device ahead to perform detection and cause your problem.

Set also a codec just in case.

Add to the logs `s.device()->pos()` and `s.device()->bytesAvailable()` to verify that.

---

I've check [QTextStream code](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/ba8342071d05336c7b7f5ff8182a2ba9000c9b53%3asrc/corelib/io/qtextstream.cpp). It looks like it always caches as much data as possible and there is no way to disable this behavior. I was expecting that it will use peek on device, but it only reads in greedy way. Bottom line is that you can't use `QTextStream` and peak device at the same time.

Comment: I tried all the combinations of QTextStream::setAutoDetectUnicode(bool) with or without QTextStream::setCodec("UTF-8") and the problem remains